# can't loop this bat file

Tags: loops, batch-file

```
for /l %i% in (1, 1, 8) do (
    set /p x=
    set /p y=
    @set  /a "z=%x%/%y%
    echo %z%
    pause
)
```

This is just an example of a problem I'm having the loop doesn't work properly. And I don't know why. I see the command prompt pop open just for a fraction of a second. It's not supposed to do that.

I want it to repeat without having to copy and paste it a bunch of times like this:

```
set /p x=
set /p y=
@set  /a "z=%x%/%y%
echo %z%
pause
set /p x=
set /p y=
@set  /a "z=%x%/%y%
echo %z%
pause
set /p x=
set /p y=
@set  /a "z=%x%/%y%
echo %z%
pause
set /p x=
set /p y=
@set  /a "z=%x%/%y%
echo %z%
pause
```

This is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: Additional notes: `set /A` does not require any surrounding `%` (or `!`) symbols, you may just write `set /A z=x/y` instead; and you have unbalanced quotes `"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your incorrect usage of the `For /L` loop, which should read `%%i`, not `%i%` and following the advice provided in the comments, your script should look like one of the following examples.

1. Without delayed expansion:

   ```bat
   @Echo Off
   For /L %%A In (1,1,8) Do (
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Call Echo Quotient as integer: %%z%%
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Call Echo Quotient as integer: %%z%%
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Call Echo Quotient as integer: %%z%%
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Call Echo Quotient as integer: %%z%%
       Pause
   )
   ```
2. With Delayed Expansion:

   ```bat
   @Echo Off
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   For /L %%A In (1,1,8) Do (
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Echo Quotient as integer: !z!
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Echo Quotient as integer: !z!
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Echo Quotient as integer: !z!
       Pause
       Set /P "x=Dividend: "
       Set /P "y=Divisor: "
       Set /A z=x/y
       Echo Quotient as integer: !z!
       Pause
   )
   ```

*Please read the usage information at the command prompt for your two main commands:*

```bat
For /?
```

```bat
Set /?
```